# solr sort by score not working properly

Tags: search, solr, relevance

I am using **Solr v6.2.1** .We are not getting accurate results using "sort score desc".

let's assume we have a list of documents in our index as below

[{
    "id": "1",
    "content": ["**java** developer"]
},

{
    "id": "2",
    "content": ["**Java** is object oriented.**Java** robust language.Core **java** "]
},

{
    "id": "3",
    "content": ["**java** is platform independent. **Java** language."]
}]

Content is defined as multivalued field in the schema

field name="content" type="text_general" **multiValued**="true" indexed="true" stored="true"

when I search for java using below query

curl http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?fl=score,id&q=(java)&wt=json&sort=score desc

I am expecting the content with **Id :2** should come first as it contains more matches related to java.But solr is giving inconsistent results.

Please suggest why I am not able to get desired results.

Comment: The number of matches is not the only factor used to calculate the score (the length of the field is also used, where shorted fields are deemed more important). Append `debugQuery=true` to your query URL to see exactly how each score is calculated. You don't have to sort by score explicitly either, that's done by default. You should also provide a field name when searching, such as `content:java`, so you're sure you're searching the field you think you're searching.

Answer (score 2):

> You need to add typeDef as edismax in your query, please find below query again.

```
 http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?fl=score,id&q=(java)&wt=json&sort=score 
 desc&defType=edismax
```

> Once you pass edismax as defType sorting on scores starts working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First, as suggested by Rahul, you should mention df or 'default query field' to execute your query explicitly on.

Secondly, your assumption about the doc with maximum occurrences of a particular term to show up as first result is not correct. What you are referring to is called **term frequency** or shortly **tf**. The ranking function used by Solr to calculate the relevance score uses 'tf', along with 'idf', the inverse document frequency. You can read more about it here [Okapi_BM25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25).

Roughly, the score translates into `(tf)*log(idf)`.

This will ensure that the most *relevant* documents for a particular query are retrieved. Intuitively, this means that, since 'Java' is present in other documents as well, the terms that differentiate doc 2 are probably 'object oriented', 'robust'.

Comment: .. but those terms are not present in the query, thus they do not affect the calculated tf/idf. But the _field length_ does, and shorted fields are usually scored higher than those with more terms.

Comment: I meant if the query had been for 'object oriented' or 'robust', then doc2 would've got a higher score.